# r sql code for counting combinations of status

Tags: sql, r

I have big dataset on SQl connection, e.g. `connection = dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "dsn", encoding = "latin1")`

In big dataset, I have 3 columns:

- ID (e.g. 111, 112, 113, etc.)
- YEAR (e.g. 2010, 2011, 2012, etc)
- STATUS (1 or 0 : non-numeric).

In dataset, each ID appears more than one (e.g. ID = 111 in 2010 has STATUS = 1, ID = 111 in 2011 has STATUS = 0, etc.)

Using SQL code, I want to find out the total number of IDs in which all STATUS in that ID is :

- A: only 0 (e.g. 45% of all rows)
- B: only 1 (e.g. 50% of all rows)
- C: both 1 and 0 (e.g. 5% of all rows)
- I also want to make list of which ID appear in A, B, C. (e.g. A = 111, 112, 115 ; B = 114, 116, etc.)

I read about function `dbGetQuery(connection, "insert sql code here")` - but I don't know how I can write SQL code to count total numbers and make list of ID.

How I can do this? Is this with window-lag function?

Comment: I think this logic?

Comment: A: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE STATUS = 1)

Comment: B: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM table
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE STATUS = 0)

Comment: C: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
FROM table
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE STATUS = 1) AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE STATUS = 0)

Comment: and to answer the other question, remove COUNT function i think. is it correct?

Comment: But I think A + B + C should equal select count(*) from table? I dont think it does

Answer (score 2):

Possible, this example help you to explain your goal

```
select gr as 'Group',sum(idRows) rowsInGroup 
  ,sum(sum(idRows))over() rowsTotal
  ,sum(idRows)*1.0/(sum(sum(idRows))over()) pct
  ,count(*) idsCountInGroup
  ,string_agg(id,',') within group(order by id) idsInGroup  --for SQL Server
from (
select id,min(status) minS,max(status) maxS
   , count(*) as idRows  -- rows by Id
   ,case when min(status) =max(status) then --assume status mast have only 2 values
           case when min(status)='0' then 'A' else 'B' end
    else 'C' 
    end gr  --Group (A,B or C)
from bigData
group by id
) t
group by gr
```

Comment: thx! is the code i provided in comments wrong?

Comment: **SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM table** count Ids, where you will count **% of all rows**

Comment: I think A + B + C should equal **select count(distinct Id) from table**

Comment: **SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM table WHERE STATUS = 1)** - count rows in group 'A'